# Does Ruby 1.9.3 support AES-NI in the OpenSSL module?

Tags: ruby, encryption, openssl

I am currently working on a project that does a lot of encryption using the attr_encryptor gem: https://rubygems.org/gems/attr_encryptor

attr_encryptor uses the OpenSSL module (http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL.html). I am using Ruby 1.9.3p374.

I am looking into ways to speed up the encryption. I have played around with AES-NI with the OpenSSL command-line and the speed up is significant enough that I want to try and modify the gem.

I searched Stack Overflow, Google, and the Ruby documentation and I couldn't find any references to AES-NI support. Does anybody know of any source code or documentation that would be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Ruby 1.9.3 *DOES NOT* support AES-NI, however Ruby 2.0.0p247 does. AES-NI is being included on line 106 here:

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_0_0_247/ext/openssl/ossl_engine.c#L106-L108

For comparison, AESNI is not being included in 1.9.3:

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_9_3_362/ext/openssl/ossl_engine.c

I wrote a simple benchmarking script using AES-256-CBC and anecdotally it does seem to run faster under Ruby 2.0.0p247.